# momentjs subtract get Nature month error

Tags: momentjs, subtraction

I used subtract function to get Nature month, but it's not work. following is my code

```
var month = moment('2013-12-31').subtract('month',1);
```

I want result is `2013-12-01` but it response `2013-11-30`.

I don't know what wrong with it?

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are subtracting the month from the date and expecting the result from the same month. it seems like moment is working fine. if you want *that* result add one more day to the response.

try this

```
var month = moment('2013-12-31').subtract('month',1).add('days',1);
```

This will subtract one month from the data and add one day to so you will get the correct response. that is first of that month.